# Android WebView disable distance

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

In my android webview I am able to scrolling outside of web content. I want to disable that. Is that possible? Same applies and for all sides and bottom. I want to scroll my page of course but I want to disable only this scrolling distances.

[image]

Comment: I do not Anjali answer there, and duplicate answers did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will help you to fit the content of Webview with the view:

```
private void setupWebView() {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {


        webView.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyApp");
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void resize(final float height) {
        MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, (int) (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is my code. WebView and img view. Image view removed after web view fully loads. Can you suggest me what should I change?? [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hq71f3?p=info)

Comment: tested and it is not working